# In VS Code, show status bar under active group?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a monitor in vertical mode, so the status bar is sometimes very far away from the active area where I'm working (see below).

Is there a way to make the status bar attach to the active group? For instance, beneath my "mainframe.txt" file, rather than the bottom of the window? Or is there, perhaps, a way to have multiple status bars (one for each group)?

[image: vertically extended vscode example]